# RunListener and QueueListener not invoked in pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to write a plugin that listens for node executions during a Jenkins pipeline. The pipeline will have some code like this:

```
stage ('production deploy') {
    input 'enter change ticket #'...
    node('prod') {
       // production deploy code here
    }
}
```

Either on allocation of node, or before any tasks run on the node, I want to verify a change management ticket has been approved. For Freestyle jobs I could use QueueListener or RunListener, but neither of these are invoked when I run a pipeline.

I can't put this code in the pipeline script because anyone that can edit the pipeline script could remove the verification.

Are there any other listeners I could hook into before, or just after a node is allocated in a pipeline?

Comment: So it seems both RunListener fireStarted and fireCompleted are invoked. I narrowed the issue down to my RunListener extension which is either not matching the targetType of Run, or `l.onStarted(r, listener)` is throwing an exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my previous implementation for freestyle builds, I had overridden the setUpEnvironment method. I didn't realize this was not called in pipeline runs - makes sense. I then implemented onStarted in my RunListener and I successfully broke into my code. Just confusion on my part.